# Call Notification from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, alarm

I have the code :

```
public void AlarmStart() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainNote.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "MESS");
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainNote.this, 1,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
}
```

It calls AlarmReceiver class on time.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
        NotifierHelper.sendNotification(?????, MainNote.class, "ba", "baba",
            2, true, true);
    } // Problem here
}
```

Then NotifierHelper  class:

```
public class NotifierHelper {

    private static final int NOTIFY_1 = 0x1001;

    public static void sendNotification(Activity caller,
            Class<?> activityToLaunch, String title, String msg,
            int numberOfEvents, boolean flashLed, boolean vibrate) {
        NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager) caller
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final Notification notify = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        notify.icon = R.drawable.icon;
        notify.tickerText = "New Alerts";
        notify.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        notify.number = numberOfEvents;
        notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        if (flashLed) {
            // add lights
            notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
            notify.ledARGB = Color.CYAN;
            notify.ledOnMS = 500;
            notify.ledOffMS = 500;
        }
        if (vibrate) {
            notify.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 1000,
                    200, 200, 200, 1000, 200 };
        }
        Intent toLaunch = new Intent(caller, activityToLaunch);
        PendingIntent intentBack = PendingIntent.getActivity(caller, 0,
            toLaunch, 0);
        notify.setLatestEventInfo(caller, title, msg, intentBack);
        notifier.notify(NOTIFY_1, notify);
    }
}
```

How can I pass `Activity caller` from AlarmReceiver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you don't need any reference to an Activity in the NotifierHelper. Use the Context (which Activity is a subclass of), eg:

```
public static void sendNotification(Context caller, ...
```

Such methods as getSystemService(), etc.. are actually exposed by Context.

And since you get passed a Context in AlarmReceiver.onReceive(), you can pass it on.