# Android - notification manager, having a notification without an intent

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent, notificationmanager

I would like to be able to fire a notification to alert the users about a timer that has finished, however i do not wish to have an intent when you click the notification.

I've tried passing in null for the intent

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

int icon = R.drawable.icon;
CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, null);
mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Just a warning about this null method - I was also looking for this answer. On my HTC Desire this causes a reboot of the device! Pretty bad, since the notification was being created on Boot - so I got into a boot-reboot-boot cycle...

Comment: Also interestingly null works fine on the 4.0 emulator. It causes a FC on my Galaxy S2 (2.3).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You may pass the parameter

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0)
```

instead of

```
null
```

on

`notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, null);`

Comment: I was calling from a broadcastreceiver and found that it was coming up with a null exception. However I tried this class I found (some guy was making a notification class) and its brilliant - check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626946/call-notification-from-broadcastreceiver

Comment: This was really helpful. I don't know, what an Intent created with an empty construcor should do, but it works perfectly on both 4.0 + and 2.2 for me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The last parameter in `setLatestEventInfo()` is a `PendingIntent` and not an `Intent`. If you need the notification to not do anything when tapped is to pass an empty PendingIntent which is done as follows: PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0).

Comment: Bot this and the accepeted answer work just fine but this one is more simple, no need to create an empty `Intent` when you can just pass `null`.

Comment: Passing `null` causes force close in android 4.1

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question and I would like to see if this works. I did a little digging and found a lot of ppl asking the same question. cbursk seems to have found a hack to get this intended functionality, which is to pass a Dialog to the notification intent instead of an Activity. I'm guessing the Dialog does nothing, or is programmed to dismiss itself right away, not sure. But I'm currently [looking at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779571/possible-to-make-an-android-notification-that-does-not-call-an-intent) and going to test it out.