# Push notifications on android 2.3 crashed.

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I am trying to send push notifications to a phone with GCM,it works fine on a device with android 4 but when I try to send notification on android 2.3 the app crashed and I am getting this error

```
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-1074787013996-1]
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required: pkg=com.itom.vreauRCA id=0 notification=Notification(vibrate=default,sound=default,defaults=0xffffffff)
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1251)
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579):     at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:274)
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:110)
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579):     at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:90)
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579):     at com.itom.vreauRCA.GCMIntentService.generateNotification(GCMIntentService.java:71)
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579):     at com.itom.vreauRCA.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:36)
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-13 11:44:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3579):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
03-13 11:44:26.374: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(3579): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
03-13 11:44:26.374: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(3579): GCM IntentService class: com.itom.vreauRCA.GCMIntentService
03-13 11:44:26.374: V/GCMBaseIntentService(3579): Acquiring wakelock
03-13 11:44:26.414: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(3579): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
03-13 11:44:26.414: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(3579): GCM IntentService class: com.itom.vreauRCA.GCMIntentService
03-13 11:44:26.414: V/GCMBaseIntentService(3579): Acquiring wakelock
```

this is my GCMBaseIntentService class

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";
    PendingIntent contentIntent;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(GetObiecte.SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        Log.d("GCMIntentService", "in GCMIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String a = intent.getStringExtra("data");
        String b = intent.getStringExtra("data2");
        generateNotification(context, a,b);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    private void generateNotification(Context context, String message,
                                                String title) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        notification.tickerText = "i-Asigutare";
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, null);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is about notification.setLatestEventInfo method.

This method was [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#setLatestEventInfo%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) in API level 11 and usage of [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) is encouraged. You may also look at [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) for usage with support library.

If you still want to go with your way, you should look at the accepted answer on this question:
[Android - notification manager, having a notification without an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040742/android-notification-manager-having-a-notification-without-an-intent)

which clearly states using like this

```
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

`notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, null);` instead of `null` you have to add an Intent, which will be started, when the user touches the notification.

From the [android developer page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#setLatestEventInfo%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

> contentIntent:    The intent to launch when the user clicks the expanded notification. If this is an activity, it must include the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag, which requires that you take care of task management as described in the Tasks and Back Stack document.