# Auto cancel Notification in android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I want to close the notification by `setAutoCancle()` method. 
Here is code of `NotifactionExample`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected void notifactionAlert() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    NotificationManager myNotifaction = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Notification Notifaction = new Notification(R.drawable.notifaction,
            "Notifaction received.", System.currentTimeMillis());


    Intent notifactionIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, notify.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notifactionIntent, 0);
    Notifaction.setLatestEventInfo(MainActivity.this, "Notifaction.",
            "you get a new notifaction...", pendingIntent);
    myNotifaction.notify(9999, Notifaction);

}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Have you check similar question on stackvoerflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179899/android-using-auto-cancel-on-a-notification-when-your-app-is-running-in-the-bac

Comment: you want to remove notification after user see or before?

Comment: i want to cancel the notification when  user click on notification.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the autoCancel Flag On.

```
Notifaction.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it onclick of any button:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setTicker("Ticker Title")
        .setContentTitle("Content Title")
        .setContentText("Notification content.")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
        noti.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Also you can check, **FLAG_NO_CLEAR**