# Android Auto - How to cancel a notification thats already sent

Tags: android, notifications, android-auto

When building my notification out this does not work to cancel the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
                        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon).setContentTitle(msg).setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setDefaults( Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS);
        ;
```

all i want to do is after the user has viewed the notification it should auto cancel. I also tried cancelling the notification right away to see if its even cancelable from the desktop head unit but it wont work. I tried the following:

```
NotificationManagerCompat msgNotificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        msgNotificationManager.cancel(myid);
```

this does not cancel the notification.  When im using the device all this works fine, just android auto wont allow the user to dismiss the notification, how can i do this ?

UPDATE: I ALSO TRIED THE FOLLOWING:

```
    PendingIntent notifyPIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
                        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon).setContentTitle(msg).setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setDefaults( Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS)
                .setContentIntent(notifyPIntent);
```

BUT it does not help, same issue.

Comment: Look this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16196933/3364157

Comment: i tried it but its still not working, i updated my question. have you tried it on android auto ? on the mobile device its working fine.

Comment: Excuse me. I did not read android car. No I have not tried in android auto

Comment: I have the same issue. The notification is cancelled in the device and in wear but not in auto.At least in the simulator. Have you tried in a real head unit?