# Android how to make notification with buttons without using Intents

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am kinda new to notifications, so please someone explain to me, how can I (if possible) make the buttons of the notification to something simple as write in the database, or the `SharedPreference`, without starting a whole activity with the `PendingIntent` that should be passed to `.addAction()`?

Answer (score 0):

For solving you're problem please take a look at this [manual](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html) .This manual contains all you need to solve you question.

Comment: I have read this tutorial, and it only exlains how to do the actions with pendign intent, I want to do it without intents if possible

Comment: Than please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040742/android-notification-manager-having-a-notification-without-an-intent